# mail sending from website

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email

I've developed a site with Python, hosted on Google Apps, and I want to send emails from that site.

Is that possible, and if so, where should I look to find out how?

Answer (score 9):

Use [the Mail API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a snippet for a quick start:

```
from google.appengine.api import mail

mail.send_mail(
    sender='anything@your-app-id.appspotmail.com',
    to='john.doe@acme.com',
    subject="Hello, World!",
    body="..."]
)
```